# How to make the line on the text disappear? Flutter

Tags: flutter

I ran into two problems with this part of the project.

1. There is a line on my text that I cannot remove.
2. I want to draw the background of the text from left and right (horizontal) to the end.

The codes of this section are as follows:

```
                        ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),
                              topRight: Radius.circular(8.0),
                            ),
                            child: Container(
                              height: 100,
                              width: double.infinity,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    topLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),
                                    topRight: Radius.circular(8.0),
                                  ),
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      image:
                                          AssetImage('assets/images/dog.jpg'))),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding:
                                    const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 78, 0, 0),
                                child: Text(
                                  'Title case',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    background: Paint()
                                      ..color = Color(0xaa000000)
                                      ..strokeWidth = 17
                                      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
```

**I did not put the button part code because it is not needed.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first issue wrap your all widgets with `scaffold` widget. For second issue you can do this:

```
ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),
              topRight: Radius.circular(8.0),
            ),
            child: Container(
              height: 100,
              width: double.infinity,
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(8.0),
                  ),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/test.jpeg'))),
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 8),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xaa000000),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  'Title case',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For 1st case you remove `background: Paint()..color = Color(0xaa000000)..strokeWidth = 17 ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke,` code from your TextStyle from `Title Case` text. You use `.stroke` that's why you see line on your case.

Answer (score 0):

It because :

```
background: Paint()
   ..color = Color(0xaa000000)
```

Change it to white instead so it the same as your background `Colors.white` or `Color(0xFFFFFFFF)` or you can remove it.